# Check variable data returns a date object

Tags: jquery, date

I have a php function which returns either an array containing numbers or a date string object, I need to know how to find out if what is returned is a date string object, below is an example of the code

**php function**

```
function dateTimerArr($timestamp){
   //only return date array if days is less than or equal to 31
   if(date("z", $timestamp)<=31){
      return array(
         's'=>intval(date("s", $timestamp)),    //seconds
         'i'=>intval(date("i", $timestamp)),        //min
         'H'=>intval(date("H", $timestamp)),        //hours
         'z'=>intval(date("z", $timestamp))     //days
      );
   }

   //otherwise return date 
   else{
      return date('d M Y | h:i A', $timestamp);
   }
}
```

**part of the jquery code**

```
success: function(data){
   if(/*if data is date string object*/){
      alert('date string object');
   }else{
      alert('in this case an array has been returned')
   }
}
```

Comment: How did that result get sent over to the client? JSON encoded? Then `$.isArray(data)` is just what you want.

Comment: yeh it is JSON encoded but i tried `$.isArray(data);` and it returns false for some reason

Comment: It should return false, if data is an array. Can you inspect the ajax call with Firebug to make sure, that the expect data gets transferred?

Comment: data returns an object `[Object object]`, the data works fine when I try to extract values from it

Comment: When a JavaScript array is given a "key", it is treated as an object. JS only treats indexed arrays as actual arrays. As soon as you're addressing `foo['key']` instead of `foo[0]` you've moved into dealing with an object.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I'll post an answer...

Comment: so if all else fails i should index my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with jQuery's isPlainObject:

```
if ( !$.isPlainObject(data) ) {
    alert('date string object');
} else {
    alert('in this case an array has been returned')
}
```